# After migrating 2007 to 2010- when i open the web application empty team site is created. no datas are visible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have followed this link for migrating SharePoint 2007 to 2010:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/migrate-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010.html

When navigating to my site after migration only the empty team site is visible. None of the data is available. Visual upgrade option is not there.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Most important in your journey should be the preparations, practically make sure after PreUpgradeCheck (on MOSS 2007 with SP2 ) and Test-SPContentDatabase (after attaching Database to the target SPS 2010) are not showing Blocking points. Ignore these would lead to lots of wasted time or even forbid migration.

Practically, you need to ensure all solutions & custom developments have been deployed to the system prior and that Test-SPContentDatabase doesn't claim needs for some more binaries.

The "database-attach" migration (which you use now) is relying on forcing the upgrade of a content database when attaching to a new SharePoint site (you can find all content databases via SP-CA > Application Management > Manage Content Databases) - with regards to the steps you followed check there to see if you removed the Content database created by the web application by default (detailed checklist also available http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607663(v=office.14).aspx#During and to validate proper upgrade check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424972(v=office.14).aspx#Verify)

In simple words following steps:

1. Create a content database using SP-CA
2. Create site collection that will use this content db.
3. Delete this content db.
4. Use STSADM to associate this newly created site collection to the
   existing content database in the back-end SQL.

With regards to Visual upgrade use this tip to enable it http://blogs.technet.com/b/chad/archive/2010/08/26/tip-38-sharepoint-2010-enable-visual-upgrade-on-sites-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: 1. There is no Custom events ,custom features in the Sharepoint 2007 site. 2. I have Run the Preupgradecheck command there is no error. only large size of data information is shown. 3. when i addcontentdb using the sharepoint management powershell "Operation Complete successfully".There is no upgrade log error.

Comment: Can you confirm you've used these steps (updated answer)? and that you could find the migrated Content database in SP-CA attached?

Comment: Yes. and then followed Steps to follow for migrtaing:

1.Take the Backup of the source site(2007) contentDB and restore the same on the target server(2010)

2.Create webapplication in sharepoint 2010.

3.once finishing it,go to central admin of 2010-> Manage content database->select the web appl created for migration_> click on database->checkin remove database-> click ok

4. Add the restored database in the target server using stsadm

Comment: But still i could not able to find the migrated content database in SP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is step 5, or late step 4 that is not done correctly since the Content databases that you should reattach seems still unattached to your new webapp.

Comment: I have reattached the content database for the same web application, at that point also having same issue